# Create an inline art shape in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

Using [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com) I want to create something like this:
[image: The word "Find:" followed by a pink rectangle, followed by more content.]

How do I create a `rect` that is inline as part of a `Flow`? Here is what I currently have:

```
flow do
  @find_color = rgb(255,0,255)
  stroke "#000"
  fill @find_color
  para "Find:"
  rect(0,0,24,24,3).click do
    @find_color = ask_color "Color to Search For"
    @find_r.text = @find_color.red
    @find_g.text = @find_color.green
    @find_b.text = @find_color.blue
    @r.style fill:@find_color
  end
  para " R:"
  @find_r = edit_line(@find_color.red,   width:30, align:'right'){ create_color }
  para " G:"
  @find_g = edit_line(@find_color.blue,  width:30, align:'right'){ create_color }
  para " B:"
  @find_b = edit_line(@find_color.green, width:30, align:'right'){ create_color }
end
```

And here is the result, showing that the `Flow` is the equivalent of a `position:relative` element in CSS, and the `rect` is using `position:absolute`:

[image: The word "Find:" is overlayed by the pink rectangle, and no space has been reserved for it.]

I tried to create a new flow inside the flow, by wrapping the `rect` call in `flow do … end`, but that caused the content to rect show up on a new line, and the `R:` label to overlap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the rect in its own flow **with a specific width** it will establish a new 'canvas' that takes up space:

```
flow do
  @find_color = rgb(255,0,255)
  stroke "#000"
  fill @find_color
  para "Find:"
  flow width:24 do
    rect(0,0,24,24,3).click do
      # ...rect click handler here...
    end
  end
  # other in-flow content here
end
```

If there are other elements with height in the parent flow then you do not need to give this flow a height; otherwise, you will need to do so for the parent flow to be held as tall as the content.